# Rewrite asynchronous dygraphs JS in synchronous-like way?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dygraphs

I am trying to use dygraphs, to make a sort-of multichannel/multitrack waveform viewer, to browse e.g. digital logic signals. The example here, renders something like this:

[image: dygraphs-example]

Obviously, I'd need the two tracks synchronized (i.e. when I zoom in one track, the other should correspondingly zoom in) - otherwise, there is not much use of this.

I have prepared a gist with the code discussed here: https://gist.github.com/sdaau/2d21ff7d88f03118bd5b31fac66d2588 ; and it should be possible to render the example via bl.ocks.org (see also [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/139778/is-it-possible-to-serve-gist-html-files-via-github-pages-or-elsewhere)), or if you run the .html files locally in your browser (I've tested with Firefox 74)

The problem is:

- When the .csv data is provided inline in the JavaScript code, synchronous calls work, - and there is no problem, synchronization works (see: [test_01_dygraphs_sync_csv.html](http://bl.ocks.org/sdaau/raw/2d21ff7d88f03118bd5b31fac66d2588/test_01_dygraphs_sync_csv.html)
- When the .csv data is provided via remote URLs, synchronous calls do not work - and synchronization does not work (see: [test_02_dygraphs_sync_csv.html](http://bl.ocks.org/sdaau/raw/2d21ff7d88f03118bd5b31fac66d2588/test_02_dygraphs_sync_csv.html))
- When the .csv data is provided via remote URLs, and the code is rewritten asynchronously - synchronization then works (see: [test_03_dygraphs_async_csv.html](http://bl.ocks.org/sdaau/raw/2d21ff7d88f03118bd5b31fac66d2588/test_03_dygraphs_async_csv.html))

The reason for this is explained in [Is there an Dygraph has loaded event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316435/is-there-an-dygraph-has-loaded-event) :

> If you pass CSV data or an array to the Dygraphs constructor, it will be called synchronously. If you pass a URL, it will be called asynchronously.

However, the problem is, I need to use .csv URLs, but I logically always think in terms of synchronous calls with this; e.g.:

```
load_g1();
load_g2();
sync_g1g2();
```

... which, as shown, breaks axes synchronization; and the kind of asynchronous calling which actually works with synchronization:

```
function load_g1() {
  ...
  g1.ready(function() {
    function load_g2() {
      ...
      g2.ready(function() {
        sync_g1g2();
      });
    }
    load_g2();
  });
}
```

... that is, "callback hell", really makes it difficult for me to manage the code.

So, I've seen questions like:

- [Rewriting JS app from Synchronous calls to Asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58954339/rewriting-js-app-from-synchronous-calls-to-asynchronous)
- [How to rewrite this asynchronous method to return the value synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194233/how-to-rewrite-this-asynchronous-method-to-return-the-value-synchronously)

... and apparently the way to do this is to use Promises - unfortunately, I'm not all that versed in JavaScript, and I cannot say if or how can this be applied to this dygraphs code.

So, to summarize: is there a way to rewrite the calls to asynchronous loading of .csv code with dygraphs, so that ultimately I can write something like these commands, in a sequence (in Initialize() in the example)? :

```
load_g1();
load_g2();
sync_g1g2();
```

For reference, I'll paste the code of `test_03_dygraphs_async_csv.html` below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dygraphs.com/2.1.0/dygraph.css">
<title>Test 03: dygraphs asynchronous (URL .csv -> synchronize() OK)</title>
<style>
#graphdiv1, #graphdiv2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#legend1, #legend2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
</style>

<h2>Test 03: dygraphs asynchronous (URL .csv -> synchronize() OK)</h2>

<hr/>

<div id="legend1" style="height:40px;">.</div>

<div id="graphdiv1"
  style="width:98%; height:200px;"></div>

<div id="legend2" style="height:40px;">.</div>

<div id="graphdiv2"
  style="width:98%; height:200px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dygraphs.com/2.1.0/dygraph.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dygraphs.com/2.1.0/extras/synchronizer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// http://dygraphs.com/tests/plotters.html
// Darken a color
function darkenColor(colorStr) {
  // Defined in dygraph-utils.js
  var color = Dygraph.toRGB_(colorStr);
  color.r = Math.floor((255 + color.r) / 2);
  color.g = Math.floor((255 + color.g) / 2);
  color.b = Math.floor((255 + color.b) / 2);
  return 'rgb(' + color.r + ',' + color.g + ',' + color.b + ')';
}

// This function draws bars for a single series.
function barChartPlotter(e) {
  var ctx = e.drawingContext;
  var points = e.points;
  var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(0);

  ctx.fillStyle = darkenColor(e.color);

  //// Find the minimum separation between x-values. .. fixed
  var bar_width = Math.floor(2.0);

  // Do the actual plotting.
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var p = points[i];
    var center_x = p.canvasx;

    ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
        bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);

    ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
        bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
  }
}


function legendFormatter(data) {
  if (data.x == null) {
    // This happens when there's no selection and {legend: 'always'} is set.
    return '<br>' + data.series.map(function(series) { return series.dashHTML + ' ' + series.labelHTML }).join('<br>');
  }

  var html = this.getLabels()[0] + ': ' + data.xHTML;
  data.series.forEach(function(series) {
    if (!series.isVisible) return;
    var labeledData = series.labelHTML + ': ' + series.yHTML;
    if (series.isHighlighted) {
      labeledData = '<b>' + labeledData + '</b>';
    }
    html += '<br>' + series.dashHTML + ' ' + labeledData;
  });
  return html;
}

var g1, g2;

function load_g1() {
  g1 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv1"),
    //"x,val1\n" +
    //"0,0\n" +
    //"18790378,1\n" +
    //"19111992,0\n" +
    //"20107172,1\n" +
    //"21101338,0\n" +
    //"183224018,0\n",
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sdaau/2d21ff7d88f03118bd5b31fac66d2588/raw/val1_data.csv",
    {           // options
      animatedZooms: true,
      stepPlot: true,
      axes: {
        x: {
          drawGrid: false
        },
      },
      includeZero: true,
      legend: 'always',
      labelsKMB: true,
      labelsDiv: document.getElementById('legend1'),
      legendFormatter: legendFormatter,
    }
  );
  // NOTE: SO:26316435 "If you pass CSV data or an array to the Dygraphs constructor, it will be called synchronously. If you pass a URL, it will be called asynchronously."
  g1.ready(function() {
    load_g2();
  });
}

function load_g2() {
  g2 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
    //"x,val2\n" +
    //"0,0\n" +
    //"18790378,0\n" +
    //"19111992,10\n" +
    //"20107172,40\n" +
    //"21101338,30\n" +
    //"22095808,20\n" +
    //"23091420,50\n" +
    //"24085288,10\n" +
    //"25080336,50\n" +
    //"26075516,40\n" +
    //"27069272,20\n",
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sdaau/2d21ff7d88f03118bd5b31fac66d2588/raw/val2_data.csv",
    {           // options
      //title: 'val2', // no need for title (y axis label) here, if using fixed ("always") legend as separate div - shown there.
      animatedZooms: true,
      plotter: barChartPlotter,
      axes: {
        x: {
          drawGrid: false
        },
      },
      includeZero: true,
      legend: 'always', // needs to be always, if we want the legend fixed, that is, not reparented to canvas, as it is for follow, which might fail with bad values
      labelsKMB: true, // seemingly only for y values, not x?
      labelsDiv: document.getElementById('legend2'),
      legendFormatter: legendFormatter,
    }
  );
  // NOTE: SO:26316435 "If you pass CSV data or an array to the Dygraphs constructor, it will be called synchronously. If you pass a URL, it will be called asynchronously."
  g2.ready(function() {
    sync_g1g2();
  });
}

function sync_g1g2() {
  g1.updateOptions({
    dateWindow: g2.xAxisExtremes() // ok, works
  });

  var sync = Dygraph.synchronize(g1, g2, { // options
    zoom: true,
    selection: true,
    range: false, // if you wish to only sync the x-axis.
  });
  // charts are now synchronized
}

function Initialize(evt) {
  load_g1();
}

Initialize();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to return a new Promise and then call resolve when you're done in place of the next action, for example, your `load_g1` function would look like this (I've removed some comments for the sake of the example)

```js
function load_g1() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    g1 = new Dygraph(
      document.getElementById('graphdiv1'),

      'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sdaau/2d21ff7d88f03118bd5b31fac66d2588/raw/val1_data.csv',
      {
        // options
        animatedZooms: true,
        stepPlot: true,
        axes: {
          x: {
            drawGrid: false,
          },
        },
        includeZero: true,
        legend: 'always',
        labelsKMB: true,
        labelsDiv: document.getElementById('legend1'),
        legendFormatter,
      },
    );
    // NOTE: SO:26316435 "If you pass CSV data or an array to the Dygraphs constructor, it will be called synchronously. If you pass a URL, it will be called asynchronously."
    g1.ready(function() {
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Your `load_g2` function would look like this

```js
function load_g2() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    g2 = new Dygraph(
      document.getElementById('graphdiv2'),
      'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sdaau/2d21ff7d88f03118bd5b31fac66d2588/raw/val2_data.csv',
      {
        // options
        // title: 'val2', // no need for title (y axis label) here, if using fixed ("always") legend as separate div - shown there.
        animatedZooms: true,
        plotter: barChartPlotter,
        axes: {
          x: {
            drawGrid: false,
          },
        },
        includeZero: true,
        legend: 'always', // needs to be always, if we want the legend fixed, that is, not reparented to canvas, as it is for follow, which might fail with bad values
        labelsKMB: true, // seemingly only for y values, not x?
        labelsDiv: document.getElementById('legend2'),
        legendFormatter,
      },
    );
    // NOTE: SO:26316435 "If you pass CSV data or an array to the Dygraphs constructor, it will be called synchronously. If you pass a URL, it will be called asynchronously."
    g2.ready(function() {
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

and your `sync_g1g2` would look like this

```js
function sync_g1g2() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    g1.updateOptions({
      dateWindow: g2.xAxisExtremes(), // ok, works
    });

    const sync = Dygraph.synchronize(g1, g2, {
      // options
      zoom: true,
      selection: true,
      range: false, // if you wish to only sync the x-axis.
    });
    // charts are now synchronized
    resolve();
  });
}
```

See how I'm calling `resolve` instead of the next action, this means that we can change your `Initialize` function to the following

```js
async function Initialize(evt) {
  await load_g1();
  await load_g2();
  await sync_g1g2();
}
```

By defining the `Initialize` function as `async`, we can make use of the `await` expression. `await` will wait for a promise to resolve before moving on to the next line.

It's also worth noting that we are not making use of the `reject` function in this example, but that is worth looking into for future use cases.

Once you get the hang of `Promises` you'll never go back! Give me a shout if this doesn't make sense.